# Difficulty accessing JSON file's content

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I would like to access this JSON file and refer to its properties.  I've tried JSON,parse() but this doesn't seem to work as '[object Object]' is what is returned.

```
var para = document.getElementById("para");
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/freeCodeCamp/ProjectReferenceData/master/GDP-data.json");
    xhr.send();

xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            var obj = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
            
            para.innerHTML = obj;
        }
};
```

Comment: innerHTML expects string html not an object. An object gets converted to string `'[object Object]' `. Try `console.log(obj)` then open browser dev tools console (F12) to inspect it

Comment: Or do something like `para.innerHTML = obj.name;`

Answer (score 0):

If you `console.log()` the obj, it will work.

Before you pass it into `element.innerHTML` you have to stringify it again with `JSON.stringify(JSON)` to convert it from an Object to a JSON string. So you might as well pass the `responseText` into the `innerHTML`

```js
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
            para.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }
};
```